How to change interface management within Palo Alto Firewall using Ansible
I want to enable SSH, HTTP for permitted IP addresses using Ansible. However, looking through the website which shows the possible parameter, there is no sign of permitted_ip or ssh, http, etc.
So i tried panos_management_profile, which has those options but it would be under
Network > Network Profiles > Interface Management instead of Device > Setup > Interfaces > Management.
This is what I have tried but it isn't what I am looking for
- name: PermitIP
  panos_management_profile:
    provider: '{{ provider }}'
    name: 'management profile'
    ssh: true
    https: true

As for panos_mgtconfig, I am unable to find out how to start since there is no parameters suited for interface management under Device > Setup > Interfaces > Management

You probably would get better help if you used PaloAlto Live Community.
